# Edit text file line by line VB6

Tags: file, vb6, edit

I use this code in this page, for reading data line by line. Now how I can edit text file, line by line?

[(VB6) Reading text files line by line looking for specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340904/vb6-reading-text-files-line-by-line-looking-for-specific-words)

```
    If InStr(1, lines(i), "sample text", vbTextCompare) Then
    lines (i)= "new text"
```

I used this code, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are editing the string array but not the text file itself.
You need to save that updated string array into the text file.

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim myFile as Integer
myFile = FreeFile
Open "C:\MyTextFileFromStringArray.txt" For Output As #myFile
For i = 0 To UBound(lines)
    Print #myFile, lines(i)
Next i
Close #myFile
```

Comment: I want just to edit a special line, and another data will be not change